# Application error on deploying my node.js project on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

On running heroku logs --tail I get the following error response:-

```
2021-06-05T13:01:57.261457+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=notes-projects.herokuapp.com request_id=631b779-6912-4467-b30-70902a2d45b fwd="103.209.223.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-05T13:01:57.640240+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=notes-projects.herokuapp.com request_id=8b2fb0bf-bc93-4bfc-8c10-1b2c553122f6 fwd="103.209.228.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my index.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

const connectDB = require("./config/db");
//connect to database
connectDB();

app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));

app.use("/register", require("./routes/register"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/notes", require("./routes/notes"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started at PORT ${PORT}`));
```

and , here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.0"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.10.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.18"
  }
}
```

note:- There is no hard coded 'PORT' in my .env file

Comment: I guess it is due to `body-parser` and you are not using it anyway. so try removing it and then make a `git push heroku master`

Comment: Generally, Node.js apps do not require an explicit `Procfile` in Heroku. It's dynamically generated. If you have defined a `Procfile` pls share.